# Parts of stored procedure just not running

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, scope-identity

I have a stored procedure which runs a series of inserts but in some cases it seems like one of the inserts isn't running but the rest of the code following it runs fine.

```
DECLARE @ID1 int
DECLARE @ID2 int

-- This works
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2)
VALUES('test', 1)
SELECT @ID1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- This picks up the correct ID

-- This sometimes doesn't seem to run or an error of some sort happens infrequently
INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
VALUES(1,2,3,4,@ID1)

-- This always runs, but if the previous insert doesn't run inserts the previous ID into @ID2
SELECT @ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Inserts the ID from the previous step and therefore is sometimes wrong
INSERT INTO table3 (field1,field2)
VALUES ('testing', @ID2)
```

This is a redacted sample of the SP. Why would this sometimes happen? I would have thought if there was an issue with the `INSERT` the rest of the procedure would bomb out? But the same code works, ran by the same person, most of the time. I have checked to see if there is any table locking going on at the same time of the issues, but there doesn't seem to be anything I can spot.

What is the best way to find out what the issue is? Or how should I restructure the above code to negate the possible impact?

Comment: in your table2 have a PrimaryKey

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler alongside the operation of this query and post up what you get in there when it silently fails to insert?

Comment: `table2` does have a primary key and it's auto-increment. The primary key field is not being inserted into in the above code.

I am running SQL Profiler now and have inserted some `TRY/CATCH` code to narrow down the issue. But I can only hang around and wait for the issue to occur as it is infrequent and seems to just happen randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Put `TRY / CATCH` around second INSERT to see possible error.

Comment: I have inserted some `TRY/CATCH` code to narrow down the issue. But I can only hang around and wait for the issue to occur as it is infrequent and seems to just happen randomly.

Answer (score 1):

Check @@Error after the insert line to see if a "silent" error is being thrown.
You could also try wrapping the insert line in a TRY/CATCH block, but I suspect that won't be fruitful, as I'm assuming you're not getting any errors in the output window of management studio?

Try running SQL Profiler alongside the running of the stored proc to see if it offers any further information regarding the failure.

The following changes to your stored proc will likely give you as much information as possible from within the SP itself as to what's occuring.
It's not perfect code, but it should provide a decent indication of any errors occuring and being "swallowed":

```
DECLARE @ID1 int
DECLARE @ID2 int

-- This works
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2)
VALUES('test', 1)
SELECT @ID1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- This picks up the correct ID

-- This sometimes doesn't seem to run
IF @@error <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error before: ' + (cast @@error as varchar)
END

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
    VALUES(1,2,3,4,@ID1)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH

IF @@error <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Error after: ' + cast(@@error as varchar)
END

-- This always runs, but if the previous insert doesn't run inserts the previous ID into @ID2
SELECT @ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Inserts the ID from the previous step and therefore is sometimes wrong
INSERT INTO table3 (field1,field2)
VALUES ('testing', @ID2)
```

Comment: I have inserted some `TRY/CATCH` code to narrow down the issue. But I can only hang around and wait for the issue to occur as it is infrequent and seems to just happen randomly.

Comment: @anothershrubery could you do a check immediately after the insert to see if the row was added, and if it was not, log the results of @@error. ERROR_Message, ERROR_Line, etc into a logging table? This would allow you to check back over time / get a trigger to fire off an email to you etc?

Comment: Yup this is what I'm doing now, but the problem hasn't came up since. (Twice yesterday and once today.) I'll hopefully see the issue if it crops up again.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch and in catch statement raise error .
Eg- :

```
CREATE PROC Usp_InsertBulkRecord
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @ID1 int
    DECLARE @ID2 int

-- This works
INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2)
VALUES('test', 1)
SELECT @ID1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- This picks up the correct ID

-- This sometimes doesn't seem to run
INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
VALUES(1,2,3,4,@ID1)

-- This always runs, but if the previous insert doesn't run inserts the previous ID into @ID2
SELECT @ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Inserts the ID from the previous step and therefore is sometimes wrong
INSERT INTO table3 (field1,field2)
VALUES ('testing', @ID2)
END TRY              
  BEGIN CATCH              
  DECLARE @Error varchar(8000)                                                            
    SET @Error= Convert(varchar,ERROR_NUMBER()) + '*****' + Convert(varchar(4000),ERROR_MESSAGE())                                                             
    + '*****' + isnull(Convert(varchar,ERROR_PROCEDURE()),'[Usp_InsertBulkRecord]')                     
    + '*****' + Convert(varchar,ERROR_LINE()) + '*****' + Convert(varchar,ERROR_SEVERITY())                         
    + '*****' + Convert(varchar,ERROR_STATE())                                                            
    RAISERROR (@Error,16,1);               
  END CATCH 

END
```

Comment: I have inserted some `TRY/CATCH` code to narrow down the issue. But I can only hang around and wait for the issue to occur as it is infrequent and seems to just happen randomly.